# Identify Teams sites at provisioning state

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

Every time a SharePoint or Teams site is created we would like to apply it as a property so we can differentiate. It will always only be a Teams site so it will have a connected Office 365 group. Is there any way to identify on a group if there is a Team connected to the group? On the properties on the group, or the propertybag on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but it sounds like you want to identify, for Office 365 Groups, if they have a Team associated or not. If so, have a look at [Get a list of groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#get-a-list-of-groups) inside this page, and you'll see that one of them has "resourceProvisioningOptions" set to Team.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "00e897b1-70ba-4cb9-9126-fd5f95c4bb78",
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": []
        },
        {
            "id": "00f6e045-f884-4359-a617-d459ee626862",
            "resourceProvisioningOptions": [
                "Team"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As per that link: 'To get a list of all groups in the organization that have teams, get a list of all groups and then in code find the ones that have a resourceProvisioningOptions property that contains "Team"'